# Copy parts of a buffer in C

Tags: c

Gang, what am I doing wrong, I am wanting to take a specific offset + a length of data out of a file and copy it into an allocated buffer of same length...

```
if( stru_ct->size != 0 ){
  unsigned char * s_buffer = malloc(stru_ct->size);
  if( !s_buffer ){
    printf( "Memory error!" );
    return -1;
    }

  fseek( file, wp->stru_ct->offset, SEEK_SET );
  fread( s_buffer, stru_ct->size, 1, file );
}
```

There's no compilation error, the s_buffer still results in 0 after the fread.  I know there's data at the offset + length.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I think this should be on stackoverflow (http://stackoverflow.com). This site is for discussions about programming in general, not specific issues in programming.

Comment: Why do you refer to `stru_ct` with `wp->stru_ct` in only one place?

Comment: "the s_buffer still results in 0" makes no sense - what do you mean by this ? Also, maybe fseek failed ? Or maybe fread failed ? You should check - use perror() or inspect errno in case they fail to learn why

Answer (score 1):

Check the return values from `fseek()` and `fread()` to make sure they're not failing.  Never assume that a call you make has succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Is `stru_ct->size` not equal to 0?  It being 0 seems like the most likely explanation for what you are seeing.